# SonarQube - SQL Server : get users and groups associated with Project in SonarQube from backend database

Tags: sql-server, sonarqube, mssql-jdbc, sonarqube-web

I need to find the list of users and group associated with project in SonarQube.

I try to find tables `user_roles` and `group_roles` that have a column `resource_id`. This can be used to get corresponding kee value in table `resource_index`. This kee value is not same as projects file kee value.

```
Select * 
into #TempTblSnprjusrs
From 
    (Select 
         users.login "lanid", users.name "Name", resource_index.kee "Kee"
     from 
         user_roles, resource_index, users
     Where 
         resource_index.resource_id = user_roles.resource_id 
         and users.id = user_roles.user_id) as x;
```

But we cannot get corresponding values of kee in projects table.

```
Select Distinct 
    #TempTblSnprjusrs.lanid, #TempTblSnprjusrs.Name,                   
    #TempTblSnprjusrs.kee, projects.Name 
from 
    #TempTblSnprjusrs
join 
    projects on projects.kee =  #TempTblSnprjusrs.Project_key;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

The database is not an API.

To get the users and groups associated with a project permission-wise, use the Administrative Security interface. Otherwise, you'll want the [permissions web services](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/api_documentation/api/permissions).

Comment: Using Administrative Security interface is through Sonar application. But I  want a report on number of SonarQube users project wise. To do so I need to run a SQL query in the database. So I need to get the right kee value to search the Projects table.